# Multiple Caret in vscode for Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When using `ctrl` + `alt` + `click` to do multiple select in vscode, sometimes it works but, most of the time it doesn't. When I try to edit keyboard shortcuts, I cannot find this shortcut anywhere. I only see the add cursor above `ctrl` + `alt` + `UpArrow` and add cursor below `ctrl` + `alt` + `DownArrow`, which does work in my case, but I'm trying to edit in places that aren't aligned.

I see small diamond with cross to the upper right of my cursor sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The default keybinding is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>.

Which can be changed in the settings: `Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> if you wish.

The underlying command is `createCursor` which is unbound by default.  You can add a keybinding in the Shortcuts Editor when you find `createCursor` - but you cannot add mouse clicks to a keybinding.

`Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier` is not what you want, it just toggles between using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to add cursors.

If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> doesn't work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> it may have already been toggled (or the setting I mentioned above `Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier` already changed from the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Look for the `createCursor` command in the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shorts editor.  Then hover over it and click the `+` that appears to its left.  In the input box that opens you can enter a new keybinding.

But as I said before, you **cannot** make a keybinding that uses mouse clicks.  You will have to chose another keybinding.

Comment: alt click doesn't work. I found a Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier though, which I don't know how to toggle click

Comment: the modifier I found has no keybinding, and the shortcut I want is default ctrl + alt + click, which I have no idea how to implement.